# Extracting two values from python regex

Tags: python, regex

I've got a file formatted like this:

```
3 name1
2    name2
1    name3
```

The space between the number and the name can be one or several spaces, or any number of tabs.

I'm trying to find a way to match this line with a regex and extract the number and the name in a list or tuple.

I could write this in several lines, but I'd rather have one clean line that can both recognize tabs and whitespace and give me my values. I've been unsuccessful in doing that.

edit: I've tried using `re.search('^[\d]+[\s|\t]+.*', line)` to match any number of digits, either spaces or tabs and then anything. But this doesn't work - presumably because I'm not telling it *what* to extract for me.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried thus far?

Comment: @ZacharyCross, sure - added above

Comment: tabs are whitespace. \s|\t is redundant. Also I don't think you know what `[ ]` does.

Comment: @Falmarri Actually, it's bugged, rather than just redundant. It allows the pipe character `|` to be matched: `bool(re.search('[\s|\t]+', '  |   '))` (that's a bunch of spaces with a `|` in the middle) gives `True`.

Comment: @jpmc26: Interesting. Does the `|` character always mean a literal in a character class? Or is this a bug in python's regex engine.

Comment: @Falmarri I couldn't point you to any documentation, but my understanding is that aside from a scare few special characters (slash, `^`, and `]` in particular), no character has any special meaning, even if it normally means something outside the character class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add parens around what you want to capture:

```
>>> line='1\t abc'
>>> re.search('^(\d+)\s+(.*)', line).groups()
('1', 'abc')
```

Incidentally, notice that the regex that you used starts with a `^` which matches only at the beginning of a line.  Consequently, `match` can be used in place of `search` here:

```
>>> re.match('(\d+)\s+(.*)', line).groups()
('1', 'abc')
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex at all, you can `str.split` it does not matter if you have 1 or 21 spaces between:

```
lines="""3 name1
2    name2
1    name3"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    num, name = line.split()
    print(num,name)
3 name1
2 name2
1 name3
```

In a list comp:

```
print([line.split() for line in lines.splitlines()])
[['3', 'name1'], ['2', 'name2'], ['1', 'name3']]
```

replace the `lines.splitlines()` with your file object in your own code.

Using a regex to split on whitespace is not a very good approach:

```
In [13]: timeit re.search('^(\d+)\s+(.*)', line).groups()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2.04 µs per loop

In [14]: timeit line.split()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 222 ns per loop
Out[15]: ('1', 'abc')
In [16]: line.split()
Out[16]: ['1', 'abc']
```

split does the exact same thing in just over a tenth of the time.

Even if there are more than two values you can split and extract the first two:

```
lines="""3 name1 foo
2    name2  bar
1    name3 foobar """


print( [line.split(None, 2)[:2] for line in lines.splitlines()])
[['3', 'name1'], ['2', 'name2'], ['1', 'name3']]
```